# create log file on external server-Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5.1

Folks, I've Googled, but nothing came out handy.

I want to create custom `Log` file using `Laravel(5.1)`, why I want, I've multiple locations where same code will be executed, so it'll be pretty hard to visit each location and view `Log` file. Currently, writing stuff to default `Laravel.log` file, working fine, but want to create some custom `abc.log` file to handle all custom logs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses the [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) package to handle logging. You can add handlers to the Monolog instance to do all sorts of interesting things with your log messages.

In [the documentation on Logging](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#logging), instructions are given on how to access the underlying Monolog instance. Once you do that, you can:

- add "Handlers" to the logger which can send messages to other logging systems, write them to the file system, send emails/SMS messages, ...
- add "Formatters" to the logger which will reformat the message however you like (HTML, text, or a format for a particular message recipient like Gelf or Loggly)
- add "Processors" which will add additional information to the messages, such as IP addresses, system stats, etc.

I have (in the past) implemented the `GelfHandler` to push messages to a Graylog server. It's pretty easy to set up. There's a [good explanation](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog) over on Laracasts.

Comment: Thanks, really helped :)